# Cron jobs on windows 2008, any other options besides windows services?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cron, service

Other than create a windows service, do window admins have any other option for creating cron jobs?

I don't like the creating/deploying windows services and was hoping for other options.

Answer (score 1):

There's Scheduled Tasks and also an "at" command (which is capable of creating jobs on remote machines as well as locally; type `at /?` at a command prompt to see the options).

Answer (score 0):

What about windows task sheduler? Any reason it can't schedule your jobs propperly?